# PHP: selecting table value inside array?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables: TOPICS and USERS.

Code here (not written by me) selects TOPICS table values and assigns them to an array:

```
$sql = 'SELECT forum_id, topic_id, topic_title, topic_time, topic_views, topic_poster, topic_posts_approved, topic_first_poster_name, topic_first_poster_colour, topic_last_post_id, topic_last_poster_name, topic_last_poster_colour, topic_last_post_time, topic_last_view_time, topic_last_poster_id
    FROM ' . TOPICS_TABLE . '
    WHERE ' . $this->db->sql_in_set('forum_id', $flast) . '
    AND ' . $this->content_visibility->get_visibility_sql('topic', 'topic') . '
    ORDER BY topic_last_post_time DESC';
$result = $this->db->sql_query_limit($sql, $this->config['last_total']);

while ($row = $this->db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
$this->template->assign_block_vars('last_topic', array(
        'LAST_LINK'      => append_sid("{$this->phpbb_root_path}viewtopic.$this->phpEx", 'f=' . $row['forum_id'] . '&amp;t=' . $row['topic_id']),
        'U_LAST_TOPIC'   => append_sid("{$this->phpbb_root_path}viewtopic.$this->phpEx", 'f=' . $row['forum_id'] . '&amp;p=' . $row['topic_last_post_id'] . '#p' . $row['topic_last_post_id']),
        'LAST_POSTER'     => append_sid("{$this->phpbb_root_path}memberlist.$this->phpEx", 'mode=viewprofile' . '&amp;u=' . $row['topic_poster']),
        'USERNAME_LAST'  => append_sid("{$this->phpbb_root_path}memberlist.$this->phpEx", 'mode=viewprofile' . '&amp;u=' . $row['topic_last_poster_id']),
        'TOPIC_TITLE'                   => $row['topic_title'],
        'TOPIC_VIEWS'                   => $row['topic_views'],
        'TOPIC_REPLIES'                 => $row['topic_posts_approved'],
        'TOPIC_LAST_POSTER_NAME'        => $row['topic_last_poster_name'],
        'TOPIC_LAST_POSTER_COLOUR'      => $row['topic_last_poster_colour'],
        'TOPIC_LAST_POST_TIME'          => $this->user->format_date($row['topic_last_post_time']),
        'TOPIC_LAST_VIEW_TIME'          => $this->user->format_date($row['topic_last_view_time']),
        'USERNAME_AV'                   => "test",
    ));
}
$this->db->sql_freeresult($result);
```

The last element in array is "USERNAME_AV". I want to assign to it data from USERS table, where table row/ user id = topic_last_poster_id (taken from TOPICS table), but not sure if it can be done inside an array.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Use `JOIN` to join a required table.

Answer (score 0):

I would achieve this by joining the users table so that you can do it at the SQL level. This provides a performance benefit in that you don't need to establish multiple database connections. All you have to do is use this syntax on your select `JOIN USERS ON (USERS.id = TOPICS.topic_last_poster_id);`

And then in your original select add `USER.USERNAME_AV as AV` and you be able to access AV much like the rest of the data.

So it'd be `$row['av']`.

Hope this helps mate! Cheers.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, JOIN will only be virtual for this php, right? I don't want to actually affect my DBs in such way.

Comment: Not a silly question at all if you're truly not familiar! No one knows everything. No it won't actually affect your database schema or database table structure.

Comment: I also had another suggestion, simply using user_helper class. What do you think about that?